# How can I fix a Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm trying to use some code from codepen and on their demo screen it works well. I have run the javascript through validators and it's ok, now I have run it through Jshint and I get these "'const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz)."

Can anyone please tell me if I have to install any packages to use ES6?
Sorry this is probably a really silly question to most of you but I can't seem to figure it out :)

Comment: JSHint is rather old. Please use ESLint instead.

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up, I'll try that now

Comment: What does JSHint have to do with "Uncaught TypeError"?

Comment: @Bramar What does the question habe to do with an uncaught typeerror (other that it's mentioned in the title, but nowhere else)

Comment: @Bramar The uncaught TypeError is what appears in the inspect tool in the browser